# How do I make a fully portable enviroment for python with VSCode, miniconda and gitbash

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, git-bash

I'm trying to make a portable enviroment for python in a USB drive. To achieve that I have downloaded miniconda, the portable version of VSCode and the portable version of GitBash. Everything works correctly except the activation of conda enviroment, the activation script located in *miniconda_path/Scripts* generates with the actual drive letter of the USB and in another computer the drive letter might change and the script fails.

How can I setup VSCode integrated terminal to activate the conda enviroment correctly.

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {        
        "GitBash": {
            "path": "PATH_TO_GITBASH\\bash.exe",
            "args": ["activation_script?"]
        }        
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to edit it when it has some changes.